# I want $name to be all rows from mysql, outside while

Tags: php, mysql

This is code sample, please add here that resolves that $name is only last vegetable :(((
I need all of them in a link:

```
<?php
    $mike = mysql_query('SELECT vegetables FROM nature');
    while($subfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($mike))
    {
        $jack = $subfile['vegetables'];
        $name = $jack;
    }                       
    //while ends                        

    echo ('<span><a href="index.php?='.$name.'">Vegetables</a>
    | 
    Fruits
    | 
    Suggestions </span>');
?>
```

Comment: you are replacing same $name in your while loop, not adding a new vegetable to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want all of them in a format something like tomato,cucumber,salad,
stack them in an array while looping over the results, and glue them together afterwards.

```
<?php
                    $mike = mysql_query('SELECT vegetables FROM nature');
                    $names = array();
                    while($subfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($mike)) {
                       $jack = $subfile['vegetables'];
                       $names[] = $jack;
                    }

                    //while ends

$list = join(',',$names);
echo ('<span><a href="index.php?='.$list.'">Vegetables</a>
| 
Fruits
| 
Suggestions </span>');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's more than cool, i'm new to php so this simplicity is amazing! :D

Answer (score 0):

Put your below code in while loop,

```
echo ('<span><a href="index.php?='.$name.'">Vegetables</a>
| 
Fruits
| 
Suggestions </span>');
```

Comment: this will display VegetablesVegetablesVegetables understand? i need Vegetables that ($name is array from database, but i dont know how to correctly do a foreach or maybe something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $mike = mysql_query('SELECT vegetables FROM nature');
    while($subfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($mike))
    {
        $name = $subfile['vegetables'];
        echo ('<span><a href="index.php?='.$name.'">'.$name.'</a>
        | 
        Fruits
        | 
        Suggestions </span>');
    }                       
    //while ends   
?>
```